# How to split a file and save with the same name as Table in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file 'test1.txt', which contains DDLs commands to create table or view. PFB the sample:

```
create or replace view test_a as select * from A.test_a;

create or replace table test_b
as select  cust_id
           ,cust_name
    from a.test_b     ;

Create or replace table test_c as select * from A.test_c;
```

I want to create 3 different files with one create command in each script. The new files must be as the same name of the object name. So in this case 3 files should be: test_a.sql, test_b.sql, test_c.sql

Things I have done as of now:

```
files = open('test1.txt','r').read().split(';')
names = ['File.'+ str(num) for num in range(len(files))]
for num,file in enumerate(files):
    open(names[num]+'.sql','w').write(file)
```

The problem I am facing is, the above script is creating 3 files with File0.sql, File1.sql and File2.sql . It's removing the ';' from the script as well. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please post code and data, not images of such.  You can create a code block using triple backticks (`\`\`\``) to start and stop the block.

Comment: Updated. Sorry about the unedited post.

Comment: I am not sure what in your DDL commands you want to modify with each new saved file.

Comment: I have a single file with all 3 CREATE or REPLACE commands, I want to split it to 3 files. Please let me know if you still thinks I need to explain it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close with your code.  Open the file, read it in, split on semicolon, write out each command to a new file.  You can also clean up the extra white-space characters surrounding each command using `strip` and append the semicolon before writing out.

```py
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as fp_in:
    commands = [c.strip() + ';' for c in fp_in.read().split(';')]

file_names = ['test_a.sql', 'test_b.sql', 'test_c.sql']

for command, file_name in zip(commands, file_names):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp_out:
        fp_out.write(command)
```

---

To automate this process you can use a regular expression to pull out the first instance of a table or view name and use it as the file name.

```py
import re

def parse_file_name(command, number):
    m = re.match('create +or +replace +(?:view|table) (\w+)', 
                 command.strip(), re.IGNORECASE)
    if m:
        return m.groups()[0] + '.sql'
    return 'UNKNOWN-{}.sql'.format(number)

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as fp_in:
    commands = [c.strip() + ';' for c in fp_in.read().split(';')]

for i, command in enumerate(commands):
    if not command:
        continue
    file_name = parse_file_name(command, i)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp_out:
        fp_out.write(command)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am getting below error:

    fp_out.write(commands)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

and in actual scenario I have a test1.txt files with 100 of CREATE or REPLACE statement. So, "file_names = ['test_a.sql', 'test_b.sql', 'test_c.sql']" 
part we need to automate. The script should read the CREATE or REPLACE <object_name> part, get the object_name from there and save the file with object_name.sql. @James

Comment: sorry, had a typo.  try it now

Comment: Thank you so much @james for your support. Is there any way we can automate the file name part instead of hard coding ? The script should read the CREATE or REPLACE <object_name> part, get the object_name from there and save the file with object_name.sql.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot @James for all your time and support. I appreciate!

Comment: No problem.  Remember to mark the question as answered (the check mark)